# Find Centroid of Cone given only depth

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, algebra-precalculus

If a glass is the shape of an inverted cone and is filled with liquid to a depth of 5cm, when half of the liquid is gone what depth remains?

How do you solve this without doing the triple integral of the region divided by volume?? I was told you can solve this without the average value method but really unsure how.

Comment: Why is the centroid relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that that volume of a cone of depth $h$ and radius $r$ is $\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h.$ Since the depth of the liquid scales with the radius at the water level, let $r=\alpha h$ for a fixed constant $\alpha.$ Then $V=\frac{1}{3}\pi \alpha^2 h^3.$ Halving the volume of water corresponds to dividing the height by $\sqrt[3]{2}$ so the remaining depth will be $\frac{5}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$ cm.